# How to call a variable in parsing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

This might be a very silly question. I am parsing 2 URLs in my project,after parsing 1st URL I get userID. Now in 2nd url I need to pass the userID. How I will put the userID in 2nd URL. What i am doing is:-

In viewdidload:-

```
NSString *str1=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/user/%@/bookmarksdata",[arrayList valueForKey:@"userId"]];
NSLog(@"%@",str1);
```

In connectionDidFinishLoading :-
NSString *returnString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataReceived encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

```
SBJSON *jsonParser=[[SBJSON alloc]init];

NSDictionary *_dict=(NSDictionary *)[jsonParser objectWithString:returnString error:nil];
```

[arrayListG addObject:[_dict objectForKey:@"userId"]];

```
NSLog(@"===%@",arrayList);
```

I am getting userId from my 1st URL, now I want to pass it in given 2nd url. Please help me how to do this..

Comment: @Rose it is nsmutable array...

Comment: @user1865424: there is no method like 'valueForKey' for NSMutableArray

Comment: @Rose how i can call the userId value in viewdidload??

Comment: @MidhunMP as per my knowledge there is..

Comment: valueForKey is for NSDictionary

Comment: @user1865424: here is the link of NSmutableArray class reference. Please read and tell me where is the valueForKey is defined https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Prince    please let me know how to solve this..

Comment: follow these step: Take a global variable string may be and after parsing first time set your id in that variable. now just after having that call your second request. to check if it's a first or second get the length of global variable, if it's > than 0 then it's second xml.. But I aim sure you can think far better way than this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call this function from your connectionDidFinishLoading

```
 [self gettingUrl:[_dict objectForKey:@"userId"]];
```

after that remove the code from the viewdidLoad.and call the first value in the viewDidload function like this

```
 [self gettingUrl:[arrayList valueForKey:@"userId"]];
```

add this function

```
-(void)gettingUrl:(NSString*)userid
{
  NSString *str1=[[NSString  alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/user/%@/bookmarksdata",userid];
 NSLog(@"%@",str1);

 }
```

Comment: @user1865424 It helped?? Then accept it by clicking on tick mark below the next to answer. :)

Comment: in viewdidload i am parsing 2 URLs..When i parse the 1st URL then i am getting userId.now this userId i have to put in the 2nd URL and then parse it..

Comment: I know i couldn't explain it properly..hav u got wat i asked??

Comment: initially how you are parsing??

Comment: i am using json framework to parse..initially i am parsing using url for that address has been provided..

Comment: let me describe u what happening in my project:-                            1)when i login using Facebook it will take access token.                 2)that access token has to be parse to get userid.                       3)that userId is to be parsed to get app access.

Comment: then you are getting userid.pass it to the function gettingUrl: then u get a url connect it and call this function gettingUrl: recursively

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20686/discussion-between-user1865424-and-rose)